# jQuery MixItUp with AngularJS NgRoute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route, mixitup

I managed to integrate jQuery MixItUp into my AngularJs app.

The items that should be displayed with MixItUp are loaded from custom services. Once all items are fetched, i trigger instantiation of jQuery MixItUp.

I'm also using AngularJS NgRoute to implement different pages.
When i first visit the page where jQuery MixItUp is used everything is fine. But when i then go to another page and back to the page with jQuery MixItUp, the filters and sorting aren't working anymore.

I setup my routes like this:

```
myApp
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // some routes for other pages
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : '/assets/js/app/views/home.html',
            controller  : 'MainController'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : '/assets/js/app/views/about.html',
            controller  : 'AboutController'
        })

        // route for page where MixItUp is used
        .when('/media', {
            templateUrl : '/assets/js/app/views/media.html',
            controller  : 'MediaController'
        })

        // 404
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo  : '/404'
        })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

In my custom directive i init jQuery MixItUp with some options and fix sorting after init. The `console.log` are logging to console everytime i visit or revisit the page. But on revisit the functionality of filters and sorting are broken.
The custom directive looks like this:

```
myApp
.directive('mixitup', function($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$on('init-mixitup', function(event) {
                console.log('[event] înit-mixitup');
                angular.element(element).mixItUp({
                    animation: {
                        duration: 200
                    },
                    load: {
                        sort: 'myorder:desc'
                    },
                    debug: {
                        enable: true,
                        mode: 'normal'
                    }
                });
            });

            scope.$on('resort-mixitup', function(event, sortCommand) {
                console.log('[event] resort-mixitup');
                angular.element(element).mixItUp('sort', sortCommand);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

In my AngularJS Controller (MediaController) i broadcast the events once all items are fetched from custom services:

```
// init
$rootScope.$broadcast('init-mixitup');

// sort
$rootScope.$broadcast('resort-mixitup', 'myorder:desc');
```

The view HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="btn-group controls">
    <button class="btn btn-lg filter"
        data-filter="all">All</button>
    <button class="btn btn-lg filter"
        data-filter=".photo">Photo</button>
    <button class="btn btn-lg filter"
        data-filter=".audio">Audio</button>
    <button class="btn btn-lg filter"
        data-filter=".video">Video</button>
</div>

<div mixItUp="mixItUp" id="mixitup-container">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items"
        id="{{ item.id }}"
        style="display: inline-block;"
        data-myorder="{{ item.date }}"
        class="mix col-xs-6 col-sm-4 {{ item.category }}">
            <img ng-src="{{ item.image }}" class="img-responsive img-circle">
    </div>
</div>
```

---

The Javascript console in chrome outputs the following on first page load:

```
[event] înit-mixitup
[MixItUp][mixitup-container][_bindHandlers] 4 filter buttons found.
[MixItUp][mixitup-container][_init] MixItUp instantiated on container with ID "mixitup-container".
[MixItUp][mixitup-container][_init] There are currently 1 instances of MixItUp in the document.
[event] resort-mixitup
[MixItUp][mixitup-container][multiMix] Operation requested via the API.
[MixItUp][mixitup-container][multiMix] An operation was requested but MixItUp was busy. The operation was added to the queue in position 1.
[MixItUp][mixitup-container][multiMix] Loading operation from queue. There are 0 operations left in the queue.
[MixItUp][mixitup-container][multiMix] Operation requested via the API.
[MixItUp][mixitup-container][multiMix] Operation started.
[MixItUp][mixitup-container][_cleanUp] Loading animation completed successfully.
[MixItUp][mixitup-container][_cleanUp] The operation completed successfully.
```

And on second page load (after moving to other pages, without browser reload):

```
[event] înit-mixitup
[event] resort-mixitup
[MixItUp][mixitup-container][multiMix] Operation requested via the API.
[MixItUp][mixitup-container][multiMix] Operation started.
```

---

There is another question relating this issue here: [How to initiate MixItUp with AngularJS NgRoute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218154/how-to-initiate-mixitup-with-angularjs-ngroute)
But there the items aren't loaded dynamically via custom services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by calling jQuery MixItUp `destroy` function when leaving the page.

I added another event listener to my directive for MixItUp:

```
myApp
.directive('mixitup', function($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$on('init-mixitup', function(event) {
                // console.log('[event] înit-mixitup');
                angular.element(element).mixItUp({
                    animation: {
                        duration: 200
                    },
                    load: {
                        sort: 'myorder:desc'
                    }
                });
            });

            scope.$on('resort-mixitup', function(event, sortCommand) {
                // console.log('[event] resort-mixitup');
                angular.element(element).mixItUp('sort', sortCommand);
            });

            scope.$on('destroy-mixitup', function(event) {
                // console.log('[event] destroy-mixitup');
                angular.element(element).mixItUp('destroy');
            })
        }
    };
});
```

And also added the event trigger in my AngularJS Controller (MediaController):

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function(){
    $rootScope.$broadcast('destroy-mixitup');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about it !!!

```
    'use strict';
  angular.module('rjApp')
    .directive('mixitup',function($timeout,$compile){
      var linker = function(scope,element,attr) {

        scope.$watch('entities', function(newVal, oldVal){

            if (element.mixItUp('isLoaded')) {
              element.mixItUp('destroy');
              element.mixItUp();
            } else {
              element.mixItUp();
            }
        },true);

      };
      return {
        link: linker,
        scope:{entities:'='}
      }
    })
```